# Disable Label click over Button but enable the mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, wpf-controls

I have a label over Button control now i want hover effect on label but i want to disable click event on label.
So here is the summary of problem.

**1**.Label is placed over Button.

**2**.I want click event of button not for Label.

**3**.Setting IsHitTestVisible="False" of label disbales the click as well as mouse over effect.

**4**.So,Now i want to disable click in label but not the mouse over effect.

Here is the code

```
<Button Content="OK" Height="25" IsDefault="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="okButton"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Click="Ok_button" Visibility="Visible" OpacityMask="#00000000"
                    Margin="-2,-3,0,0" IsTabStop="False"   />
            <Label Content="OK" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="OKLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="141" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black"
                   BorderThickness="0" OpacityMask="Black" Foreground="White" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource oklabel}" IsEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            </Label>


        <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="oklabel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" Color="White"/>

                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

        </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity? Why would you want a label over the top of a button? Why not just make the button include whatever your label would be?

Comment: HI Chris thanks for your valueable time....i am a newbee in WPF, so the problem was
When i put button and press it,it starts blinking....so i decided to do this in this way.
Do you have any suggestion how can i get rid of this blinking behavior of button?